# x||y vs. mapply(function(x,y) x||y,x,y) in [R]

Tags: r, functional-programming, mapply

I think I have little syntax sugar issue using [R] :

```
x=rnorm(1000,mean = 1,sd = 1)
y=rnorm(1000,mean = 1,sd = 1)
x=x>1
y=y>1
x||y
mapply(function(x,y) x||y,x,y)
```

Basically I want to obtain a list of type boolean where an element is TRUE when either the corresponding element in x and y are TRUE

but

```
x||y
```

returns a scalar value of TRUE whereas

```
mapply(function(x,y) x||y,x,y)
```

does the job.

So what did I get wrong on the

```
x||y
```

syntax?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do `x | y` to obtain a vectorized result. `x || y` only compares the first element of `x` to the first element of `y`.

To understand this, consider the following:

```
TRUE | FALSE
# [1] TRUE
TRUE || FALSE
# [1] TRUE

c(TRUE, FALSE) | c(TRUE, FALSE)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
c(TRUE, FALSE) || c(TRUE, FALSE) # only first element is compared
# [1] TRUE

c(FALSE, TRUE) | c(FALSE, TRUE)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
c(FALSE, TRUE) || c(FALSE, TRUE) # only first element is compared
# [1] FALSE
```

`mapply` is not needed here, because that is just recreating the behavior of `|`:

```
identical(c(FALSE, TRUE) | c(FALSE, TRUE), mapply(function(x,y) x || y, c(FALSE, TRUE),c(FALSE, TRUE)))
# [1] TRUE
identical(c(TRUE, FALSE) | c(FALSE, TRUE), mapply(function(x,y) x || y, c(TRUE, FALSE),c(FALSE, TRUE)))
# [1] TRUE
```

`mapply` is also far more computationally expensive:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(mapply(function(x,y) x||y, x, y), x | y)
Unit: microseconds
                                expr      min       lq       mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 mapply(function(x, y) x || y, x, y) 1495.294 1849.006 2186.77275 2012.776 2237.936 5320.702   100   b
                               x | y   27.713   28.868   39.97163   33.871   38.297  166.657   100  a
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks a lot - although I think Pascal's explanation is the correct one